# CMake can't find Boost_LIBRARIES variable

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

Final Edit: Solved.
Guys the problem occured because of the "WinSock32".
I've added

```
target_link_libraries(modernC__ -lws2_32)
```

and the code has been builded.

I have been using the Boost library on CLion in Ubuntu for about 1 year. But this week I also decided to install it on the Windows operating system.
so I downloaded the Boost library on GitHub and installed the Boost library using Find.Boost first and then "Find.Boost".

After writing the necessary commands in CMake settings section in CLion, I noticed that the variable $ {Boost_LIBRARIES} is empty.

When I don't use the message () function, the "CMake" part of the project does not give an error, but I get the error "undefined reference" after "build". Below are the CMake commands I wrote on CLion and the errors I received.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(modernC__)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
find_package(Boost 1.66.0)

message(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
message(${Boost_FOUND})
message(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

IF (Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable(modernC__

        main.cpp

        #concurrencyExampleOne.cpp

        #adapterExampleOne.cpp
        )
target_link_libraries(modernC__ ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
    message(${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

My output is:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.1.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\Berke\CLionProjects\modernC++
C:/boost/include/boost-1_66
TRUE
C:/boost/lib
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:22 (message):
  message called with incorrect number of arguments


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

In this case, obviously Cmake is currently unable to find the .lib files that should link to my code. 
My question is; How can I permanently drop .lib files into this variable, or is there any other way to do this?

If I do not use "message(${Boost_LIBRARIES}" so the compiler gives me this error;

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable modernC__.exe
CMakeFiles\modernC__.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `ZNK5boost6system14error_category12std_category10equivalentEiRKSt15error_condition':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_66/boost/system/error_code.hpp:676: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_66/boost/system/error_code.hpp:679: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
CMakeFiles\modernC__.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `ZNK5boost6system14error_category12std_category10equivalentERKSt10error_codei':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_66/boost/system/error_code.hpp:706: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_66/boost/system/error_code.hpp:709: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
C:/boost/include/boost-1_66/boost/system/error_code.hpp:721: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
CMakeFiles\modernC__.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `ZN5boost4asio5error19get_system_categoryEv':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_66/boost/asio/error.hpp:230: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
CMakeFiles\modernC__.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `ZN5boost4asio6detail17winsock_init_base7startupERNS2_4dataEhh':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_66/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:39: undefined reference to `_imp__WSAStartup@8'
CMakeFiles\modernC__.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `ZN5boost4asio6detail17winsock_init_base7cleanupERNS2_4dataE':
C:/boost/include/boost-1_66/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:56: undefined reference to `_imp__WSACleanup@0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\modernC__.dir\build.make:86: modernC__.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:75: CMakeFiles/modernC__.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/modernC__.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: modernC__] Error 2
```

Comment: The `Boost_LIBRARIES` variable should be populated correctly. However, it looks like you may not have the libraries built for MinGW. Did you build these?

Comment: My computer has mingw-64 installed and the necessary parts are attached to the system environment variables. Do I need to do anything extra?

Comment: You need to *build* Boost for the MinGW compiler. How did you build Boost on your Windows machine? Which compiler did you target?

Comment: I have followed this instructions : https://gist.github.com/sim642/29caef3cc8afaa273ce6

Comment: Can you locate the Boost libraries on your system? The MinGW-compatible libraries should have a `mgw` in the name (e.g. `libboost_filesystem-mgw48-d-1_66.dll`).

Comment: Yes sir,
My lib folder at; C:\boost\lib and some of libraries are;

libboost_chrono-mgw81-mt-d-x32-1_66.dll, 
libboost_chrono-mgw81-mt-d-x32-1_66.a, 
libboost_container-mgw81-mt-sd-x32-1_66.a, 
etc.

Comment: Ok, they do say `mgw` which is good, but they also say `x32`. So, they are probably 32-bit libraries. Is your MinGW also 32-bit?

Comment: The problem has been solved. Library was installed very well without any problem. But I was trying to ASIO code in Windows without linking winsock32 library. So i just added ""the target_link_libraries(myprojectName -lws2_32)"" line.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Great! Please consider writing an answer post explaining this, and showing your updated code, so that other viewers to your question can easily see what the solution is.

Comment: Yes, I edited my question and added a "Final Edit Part". I hope it is the correct way.

Comment: This is a Question and Answer site (see the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page), so the Answer should be in a *separate* answer post, and checked as **accepted** if it is the **correct** solution.

Comment: Alright, I will send another post :) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should specify boost libraries (as components) explicitly.
And you should add libraries to target.

Like this:

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem system locale context REQUIRED)

...

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ...
  ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
  ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
  ${Boost_LOCALE_LIBRARY}
  ${Boost_CONTEXT_LIBRARY}
  ...
  )
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. So I think I should build the library again. This time I can use CMake Gui maybe.
Should I install Boost.Find when I use CMake Gui do you know?